# MemberQ weird inside Compile

Tags: compile

```
Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, MemberQ[x, 2]][{2}]
```

outputs `False`.

In fact, it seems to get compiled as `False` for every input if you look at a `CompilePrint`. It doesn't call the main evaluator, and `MemberQ` is included in the `` Compile`CompilerFunctions[] `` list

Any ideas?

Comment: `Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}}, MemberQ[x, 2]]` works; `Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, MemberQ[x, 2.]]` also works. `MemberQ[{2.}, 2]` might help you figure out why.

Comment: @JM, I'm not sure of the protocol, but I'll post an answer and if that's not what I'm supposed to do, I'll delete it. I'll sure delete it if you post yours

Comment: No worries, I upvoted your answer. I didn't feel like elaborating today, and wanted you to piece things together yourself, so I just left a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, as J. M. pointed out, it was an issue of types. `x` was defined to be of *Real* type, so it was converted and treated as such in the compiled code. 
Since a `2` can never be a member of a vector of *Reals*, the compiler hard-coded the result `False`, which is correct.

Comment: In general: if you're going to be dealing with reals entirely within your compiled code, make all hard-coded constants reals, and similarly with integers. `With[]` might be useful here for injecting things like `N[Sqrt[2]]` or `N[Pi]` into your code to be compiled.

Answer (score 9):

Some more insight can be obtained using `CompilePrint`:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[
 Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
  MemberQ[x, 2]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(ie, it works out that it's always false due to the type), versus

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[
 Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}},
  MemberQ[x, 2]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which does the usual thing.

Comment: huh, didn't know about CompilePrint, nice!